# Posicionamento de ImageButton no XML

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tenho um imagebutton em um relative layout. Quando coloco o comando:

"android:layout_marginLeft="

Ele faz o pretendido (se afastar da borda da esquerda em x medida), mas quando coloco:

"android:layout_marginRight=" nada acontece.

Alguém saberia me explicar o porque? ou qual comando eu devo usar para que o espaçamento se de a partir do "começo da tela" na parte da direita?

Comment: Não consegui o porquê de não estar funcionando porque eu não tenho acesso ao código completo do componente, então fica difícil dizer alguma coisa. :/

Answer (score 1):

Esta é a configuração necessária para que o seu `ImageButton` alinhe-se de acordo com o inicio e fim da tela. Verifique se não há nenhum alinhamento com o `Parent`, que no caso é o `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        //::layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp
        //::layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- Os atributos `marginStart` e `marginEnd` são **opcionais**.

Comment: Então eu tenho que colocar os dois comandos necessariamente? inocência minha colocar só um dos dois achando que o outro seria colocado automaticamente?

Comment: Não necessariamente. Inocência nada, besteira, rapaz. Tu se enganou com o atributo `margin`. Normal isso.

Comment: Se tu quer aplicar o posicionamento apenas para a esquerda e direita, use o marginLeft e MarginRight. Se tu quer colocar nos dois, sem precisar colocar os dois atributos, usa esse: `margin="10dp"`

Comment: Mas ao usar o `margin` tu está adicionando atributos para todas as posições, que são elas: `top` `bottom` `right` `left`